# Pixel Artifacts on Rendered Image with HDRi

Tags: rendering, octane-render-engine

i'm currently facing Issues when rendering a Scene with Octane while using an HDRi Texture Environment.

Rendered with 1920x1080 with 4096 Samples.
Comparison (HDRi Texture Environment vs Daylight Environment):
[image: Comparison_TextureHDRi_vs_Daylight_Environment]

The Issue is still there with the Daylight Environment, but due to it being an Animation its not that big an issue. Also tried raising the Sample Amount to 16000 Samples, but it seems to get worse the more samples i set.

This are the Environment Settings (Daylight):
[image: daylight_environment_settings]

And here for the HDRi Texture Environment:
[image]

I'm using the Path Tracing Kernel with Blender V3.6 with Octane Server Prime 2022.1.2.27.17.
Except Samples, everything on Default Values.
I also tried different Kernels (Photon Tracing and Direct Light) - same Issue.

When using Denoise in Compositing, the Image gets all messed up and very blurry.

(It is both in Animation Rendering and "Still Image" Rendering)

Can someone please help?

Edit 1:
So, appreantly, this issue comes from Caustics. After checking "Allow Caustics" on all Materials that are affected, deactivating "HDR" on the Denoise Node in the Compositor and increasing Roughness on Materials that were the most affected, i was able to reduce the Effect. But i couldn't get rid of it.
See: [Caustics and the Photon Tracing Kernel](https://help.otoy.com/hc/en-us/articles/14458811751067-Caustics-and-the-Photon-Tracing-Kernel)